# AJAX: JSON data doesn't return correct value

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, ajax

I'm working with a login form. i have some issuee about the return value of Json data and i don't know why :/

If i try my code, in my database the data are correctly saved (username/password/email), and the 'if' controls seems work fine (user already register, double email, etc)
btw:
In my cycle

```
if(data === "1"){...}

else if(data==2){...}
```

etc.

the function return me always a wrong value.
i've also tried with a boolean form, with

```
if(data.success){
...
}else{
...
}
```

but it seems not work anyway :(
it bring me back always in the 'else'

this is my HTML:

```html
<div class="form">
        <form method="post" class="register-form">
            <fieldset>
            <b>Nome utente:</b>
            <input type="text" id="username_r" placeholder="inserisci nome utente"  maxlength="16"/>
            <b>Password:</b>
            <input type="password" id="password_r" placeholder="inserisci password" maxlength="30"/>
            <b>Conferma password:</b>
            <input type="password" id="conferma_password" placeholder="inserisci password" maxlength="30"/>
            <b>Indirizzo email:</b>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email" maxlength="35"/>
            <p id="error"></p>
            <input id="register_input" type="submit" value="registrati">
            <p class="message">Già registrato? <a href="#">Esegui il login</a></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
</div>
```

[Login.js]

```js
$("#register_input").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var username1 = $('#username_r').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var password1 = $('#password_r').val();
  var password2 = $('#conferma_password').val();
  
  username1 = username1.replace(/[" "]/g, "");
  email = email.replace(/[" "]/g, "");
  password1 = password1.replace(/[" "]/g, "");
  password2 = password2.replace(/[" "]/g, "");
  
  var myRegEx = /^[A-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-z0-9\._-]+\.[A-z]{2,6}$/;
  
  if(username1 === "" || email === "" || password1 === "" || password2 === ""){
   $("form #error").html("Devi riempire tutti i campi per registrarti.");
  } else if(password1.length<6){
   $("form #error").html("La password deve avere almeno 6 caratteri.");
  } else if(password1 !== "" && password2 !== "" && password1 !== password2){
   $("form #error").html("Le password inserite non sono uguali.");
  }else if(!myRegEx.test(email)){
   $("form #error").html("Indirizzo email non valido.");
  } else {
   $.ajax({
    url:"php/loginFunction.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{username:username1, email:email, password:password1},
    success:function(data){
     data = JSON.parse(data);
     data = data.esito;
                    //*** Here the problem ***
     if(data === "1"){
                                                $("form #error").html("Registrazione eseguita correttamente!");
      window.location.replace("http://localhost/progetto/home.php");
     } else if(data === "0"){
      $("form #error").html("Username già esistente.");
     } else if(data === "2"){
      $("form #error").html("Email già in uso.");
     }
    },
    error: function(){
     alert("Si è verificato un errore, riprovare più tardi.");
    }
   });
  } 
 });
```

[LoginFunction.php]

```js
function registrazione($username, $password, $email){
 try{
  $db = db_connect();
  $username = $db->quote($username);
  $password = $db->quote($password);
  $email = $db->quote($email);
  
  $query = "INSERT INTO utente(username, password, email)
    VALUES(".$username.", ".$password.", ".$email.")";
  
  $res = $db->exec($query);
  if($res){
   $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
   $query = "SELECT id_utente
    FROM utente
    WHERE username=".$username;
   $rows = $db->query($query);
   foreach($rows as $row){
    $_SESSION["id_utente"] = $row["id_utente"];
   }
   return 1; // registrazione effettuata con successo
  } else {
   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS email_presente
    FROM utente
    WHERE email=".$email;
   $rows = $db->query($query);
   foreach($rows as $row){
    if($row["email_presente"]=="1"){
     return 2; //registrazione non effettuata, l'emai inserita è già presente nel db
    } else return 0;
   }
  }
  return 0; // registrazione non effettuata
  
 }catch (PDOException $ex){
  return -2; // errore
 } 
}
```

*** EDIT ***

this is the first part of my [loginFunction.php]

```js
<?php include_once("db.php");?>
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["email"])){
 $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
 $password = md5(htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]));
 $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
 $regReturn = registrazione($username, $password, $email);
 $array = array("esito"=>$regReturn);
 $json = json_encode($array);
 print $json;
} else if(isset($_POST["username"])){
 $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
 $password = md5(htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]));
 $loginReturn = login($username, $password); 
 $array = array("esito"=>$loginReturn);
 $json = json_encode($array);
 print $json;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `==` instead, there might be data type difference.

Comment: You don't appear to be echoing a response to the request, only returning a value from the function which won't necessarily be returned to the AJAX request. Also note that a plain text response will probably have some whitespace around it. Try `if (data.trim() === "1") {`. Finally, returning plaintext values is a bad idea. I'd strongly suggest you use a structured format such as JSON or XML

Comment: In the PHP, please show us where you actually return the JSON data to the browser...we can't see that part

Comment: And in the JS, just after `success:function(data){`, please write `console.log(data);` and then tell us what the result is. Then we know if your code is reading the data structure correctly or not. (P.S. That is really a simple debugging thing you should be doing already)

Comment: what is from data.esito doing ? can you comment it out ?

Comment: i've edited the post with the first part of my 'loginFunction.php'